# Need help connecting my App Engine PHP with my Google Cloud SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, google-app-engine

Below is the sql connection code for my php script as it attempts to connect to my Google SQL Cloud Database

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect(":/cloudsql/projectID:google-cloud-instance","root","root","DATABASE");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Oops! Something Must Have Went Wrong?: " . mysqli_connect_error()
;`
```

but when I process the overall php script i get the following error:

```
"php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0Error:"
```

I am a beginner at this, so if someone can help me..

1. Understand what this means
2. How the heck can I fix?

Thanks in Advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the cloud SQL instance name as the 'socket' parameter to the MySQLi [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). For example

```
$instance_name = ":/cloudsql/projectID:google-cloud-instance";
$c = new mysqli(null, $username, $password, $database, 0, $instance_name);
```

if you're using the default auth (application level auth) then you can pass root and no password to connect.

```
$instance_name = ":/cloudsql/projectID:google-cloud-instance";
$c = new mysqli(null, "root", "", $database, 0, $instance_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Connecting_to_your_Cloud_SQL_instance. It seems like you are mixing mysqli and mysql_connect syntaxes. Pick one and follow the example in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and speedy response, however, I have attempted to change this and it is still erring out. Not sure you have some code examples that you may be trying to illustrate?

Answer (score 0):

For CloudSQL, it's recommended that you use the unix socket.

If you're using mysqli_connect, you can specify the default socket in php.ini.

`php.ini
mysqli.default_socket= '/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME'`

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DB');