# Error while trying to connect to an external DB server from Google App Engine

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I have a scenario where for a certain reason I cannot use Google's Cloud SQL. Hence I want the application at appid.appspot.com to connect to an external DB server.

DB.php

```
'hostname' => '202.202.202.202',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'dbname',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
```

This gives me a Server Error, however I'm able to connect to the database from mysql workbench. This application does not have a problem while connecting to Cloud SQL.

Error message:

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: "Gives me a Server Error" -- such as?

Comment: @JeremyHarris I'm sorry I have included the error message in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Anything in the logs? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

Comment: No nothing specific to this error. However if I change hostname from IP to host.domain.com I do not get the server error but I get "Message: mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0"

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818997/need-help-connecting-my-app-engine-php-with-my-google-cloud-sql-database

Comment: I saw that link but I'm not using Cloud SQL, I'm using a MySQL on a different server.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Probably a firewall issue then. You might need to whitelist the external IP.

Comment: But I'm able to connect to it from Mysql workbench. From any IP actually and the firewall for 3306 is open.

Comment: I mean Google themselves may be blocking it. Workbench isn't running on their server.

Comment: Possible. Any idea how I can whitelist the IP?

Comment: No idea. I tried searching around and there may be issues with free accounts or vendor lock-in stuff. Maybe contact them for support?

Comment: I do not have support with them.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following changes and got it working.

Instead of IP address I gave the external DB server a hostname.

```
'hostname' => 'dbserver.example.com',
'username' => 'user',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'dbname',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

Then I activated billing for the Google App Engine project. Once you activate billing the Google Socket API will start functioning.

Please do not try immediately. Give it sometime and this should start working just fine.