# Connection between Google Cloud SQL and Google App Engine - Time out

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I'm setting up an app that needs to connect to a database on the cloud (google cloud sql). I have a php file that connects to the database and returns all  data that I need. It works fine on local host but I can't make it work on the cloud.

**Here's my .php file:**

```
<?php


$conn = mysqli_connect("[MY_GOOGLE_SQL_PUBLIC_IP]", "root", "123", "mysql");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}else{

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) . PHP_EOL;


}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

**Here's my app.yaml:**

```
runtime: php55

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: cloud-test.php

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "cloudtest-2412**:southamerica-east1:store"
```

If I run on my local host (127.0.0.1:8888) the php file, I get that the connection with my database on google sql was made. But when I deploy (gcloud app deploy) to the app engine and try to access the url provided by google, I get the following error:

**Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2002 Debugging error: Connection timed out**

*The sql database and the app engine are in the same project so I shouldn't need to give any special permission (like I have to give the permission for my local ip when accessing on my local host)

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Instance connection name` （`cloudtest-2412**:southamerica-east1:store`) instead of `MY_GOOGLE_SQL_PUBLIC_IP` to connect.

You can find that on the Instance details page for your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I got it working by adding the following this code: `$conn = mysqli_connect(null, "root", "123", "mysql","0","/cloudsql/cloudtest-2412**:southamerica-east1:store");` (got it from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818997/need-help-connecting-my-app-engine-php-with-my-google-cloud-sql-database). Something about the socket... Thanks